# c++ method returning a different type based on a string

Tags: c++, templates, return

I am fighting with the following issue for some time:

I have several data types in my application, and they are used like (very simplified code):

```
QVector<Function*> Container::getFunctions() {return mFunctions};
QVector<Procedure*> Container::getProcedures() {return mProcedures};
....
QVector<Function*> mFunctions;
QVector<Procedure*> mProcedures;
```

Both `Function` and `Procedure` are derived from a class `ObjectWithUid` which has

```
virtual QString getClassUid() = 0;
```

and both `Function` and `Procedure` are implementing the virtual method and each of them is returning the respective class uid (for functions this is `"CUID_FUNC"` and for procedures this is `"CUID_PROC"`).

And now, I have a method somewhere else:

```
template <class T> void showObjectList(const QVector<T*> items)
{
   // show the list of objects
}
```

which is used like:

```
showObjectList(getFunctions());
```

or

```
showObjectList(getFunctions());
```

and as expected I can show either the functions or procedures.

But now I want to be able to show the list based on the class uid of some object, so I would need code like:

```
ObjectWithUid* obj = giveMeMyObject();

showObjectList(< a vector to which the object belongs determined based on class UID >)
```

*And here the problems start*

I wrote the following method:

```
template <class T> QVector<T*> getListOfObjectsForUid(const QString& uid)
{
    if(uid == uidFunction)
    {
        return getFunctions();
    }

    return QVector<T*>();
}
```

and I'm trying to use it like:

```
ObjectWithUid* obj = giveMeMyObject();

showObjectList(getListOfObjectsForUid(obj->getClassUid()));
```

and the compiler yells: `error: no matching function for call to getListOfObjectsForUid(const QString&) candidate is template <class T> QVector<T*> getListOfObjectsForUid(const QString& uid)`

How can I achieve what I'm looking for? IE: return a vector of different objects based on a string property in a way that I can use it automatically without having to specify the type...

Comment: C++ is a *statically* typed language. This means types of all expressions and variables must be known statically, that is, by examining the program text, without ever having to run it. Therefore what you want is not possible and you have to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to specify statically T somehow.

This

```
  showObjectList(getFunctions());
```

implicitly specifies `T=Function*`, but

```
  showObjectList(getListOfObjectsForUid(obj->getClassUid()));
```

is ambiguous because `getListOfObjectsForUid` only has the template parameter in the return type.

You can resolve the ambiguity manually:

```
  showObjectList(getListOfObjectsForUid<ObjectWithUid>(obj->getClassUid()));
```

Since all your object types inherit from `ObjectWithUid` and the return type is actually `QVector<ObjectWithUid*>` and not just `QVector<ObjectWithUid>`.